# made string a integer but it saying i didnt

Tags: python, api

So im working with rights api at the moment and im trying to grab something called "tier" and for example it could be "SILVER" so when i call apoun it `print(my_ranked_stats['tier'])` it comes up with the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

for example this is the data it would get

```
{
   "leagueId":"c60807e8-6afb-38fd-ab9b-ae8588dc8b27",
   "queueType":"RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
   "tier":"CHALLENGER",
   "rank":"I",
   "summonerId":"6CfZ3nw63SwMi1e786wyzoMJNMXW0RJst0Dsgyy5mw7dmjw",
   "summonerName":"Doublelift",
   "leaguePoints":931,
   "wins":160,
   "losses":133,
   "veteran":true,
   "inactive":false,
   "freshBlood":false,
   "hotStreak":false
}
```

Ive tried to also turn it into a int  with
`tier = int(my_ranked_stats['tier'])`

Comment: Despite what you've posted above, that error means `my_ranked_stats` is actually a list. You can't use a string as the index for a list (i.e. `tier`) - you need to use an int or slice - e.g. `my_ranked_stats[0]`. Please update with the real data coming back from the API.

Comment: I imagine that my_ranked_stats is a list. Try *print(my_ranked_stats[0]['tier'])* and see what happens

Comment: so making it so it so `my_ranked_stats[0]` worked but the problem is when i want to use the name for example "disco inferno" it comes up saying `KeyError: 'tier'` but it works if i change it to `my_ranked_stats[1]` it then works but im using it in discord so i would type "$api disco inferno"(works with [1]) or "$api Killogee"(works with [0])

Comment: That means that the second element in the list doesn't have a `tier` key. If you get the field with `my_ranks[1].get("tier", "undefined")` you'll get `undefined` as default value (2nd parameter) if the specified key (1st parameter) can't be found.

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work with `my_ranked_stats[0]` but does when I change it to `my_ranked_stats[1]`.

Comment: I believe there is more data in the API response than what you posted. You should probably post an entire response for us to see what is happening.

Answer (score -1):

Because it looks like your data is a JSON format you should first specify the index of that list you want to get so first loop through it like:-

```py
for i in range(len(my_ranks)):
      Print(my_ranks[i]["tier"])
```

But if that is not the case and youre data is just one entity you can access the value in a `dictionary` like

```py
Tier = my_ranks.get("tier")
Print(Tier)
```

Or using an Index for ex. `my_rank[2]`

Comment: "Because it looks like your data is a JSON format you should first specify the index of that list" that doesn't make sense, JSONs are not necessarily lists, they could be very well represented with a dictionary like the one the author posted. "if [...] your data is just one entity you can access the value in a dictionary like `Tier = my_ranks.get("tier")`" That is true, you can do that, but it doesn't solve the author's issue because they are already trying to access the value of that key.

Comment: "Or using an index for ex. `my_rank[2]`" No, while it is possible to use integers as keys in a dictionary (although it is highly discouraged), it is not possible that the keys of a JSON dictionary are integers, and thus when deserialized they will all be strings. Extra side note: python's `print`s are lowercase.

Comment: Just to clarify a list can has JSON values that is to say you are trying to access the wrong data rather access an item in this case a Value Key pair is not applicable that is why the error says it is an indice problem which should be an index rather than the dictionary key.

Comment: I tried to give the author multiple options to try because i don't know the exact information and procedures he want to go with this problem, plus "Or using an index for ex. `my_rank[2]`" well yet it is i believe to be true why? Because the author my want to access an specific index rather than the first also on a side note thank you for the capitalization Tip

Comment: I understand. I suppose your answer has a few grammar mistakes but so does the question.

Comment: Yup hope i sent the point accross tho lol